# SSL certificates ca-certificates.crt and ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem expired - what do?

Tags: debian, security, ssl, certificates

When running `sudo lynis audit system` it tells me that two of my SSL certificates expired, namely: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt and /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem.

What should I do to fix this problem? Remove those certificates? If so how? I'm using Debian 9.1 with KDE.

Comment: Note that that certificate is created by Debian's `ssl-cert` package.

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` should not be just "your" SSL certificate. It should be a concatenation of all CA certificates that are trusted by OpenSSL, for programs that want the list of trusted CA certificates all in a single file.

Some programs that use OpenSSL will instead want the trusted CA certificates as separate files in a directory, with filenames that are certificate hashes of the form `HHHHHHHH.N` where the N is usually 0 (if there are two or more certificates with identical hashes, the first will have the suffix `.0`, the second `.1` etc). This is done by symbolic links in the `/etc/ssl/certs` directory.

Both forms are managed by a `update-ca-certificates` command, which is controlled by the `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` file. The actual master copies of the root certificates are in sub-directories of `/usr/share/ca-certificates/` (and `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` if you're chosen to add custom root certificates in The Debian Way).

If you want to exclude some of the default CA certificates (e.g. because they are expired and you are under orders to remove any expired certificates from the system configuration), you should edit `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`, prefix the appropriate line with an exclamation mark, and then run `update-ca-certificates` as root. For your custom CA certificates, you should remove them from the `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/*` sub-directory before running `update-ca-certificates` instead. Otherwise, `update-ca-certificates will just add it back whenever the`ca-certificates` package is updated or reconfigured.

Note that having expired certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs` should not normally be a problem: OpenSSL library functions will check for certificate expiration and will report expired certificates as a validation failure. Of course, if you have a system with no knowledge of real time and date, or a badly-programmed application that ignores certificate expiration, then you have a legitimate reason to remove expired certificates from configuration.

---

If you want to regenerate the `/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` certificate, the command for that is:

```
make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
```

This will overwrite the certificate `/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` with a new self-signed certificate, and the file `/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` with the corresponding new private key.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a "ca-certificates" package on your distro's package repository.

Upgrade that package and your installed CA certificates will be upgraded.

Btw, if you remove ca-certificates.crt from your system, you won't be able to trust anyone's SSL certificate.

Comment: It's already the latest version of the official Debian repositories but I still get that warning!

Comment: Which version of Debian are you using?

Comment: The latest one: 9.1. (No particular distribution but the original Debian from the official website installed from DVD.)

Comment: Try with command `update-ca-certificates`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The output of `sudo update-ca-certificates` is: `Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
Updating Mono key store
Linux Cert Store Sync - version 4.6.2.0
Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

I already trust 166, your new list has 166
Import process completed.
Done
done.` and I still get that warning.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm I'm running out of ideas, you could try to manually check if the warning is real by inspecting the certificates contained in that file, hopefully there's some website that can help you with it. Also maybe it's a good idea to join the Debian-users mailing list and ask there.